# dynamic queries in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, dynamic-sql

I would like to write a query and allow for a grouping on different colums; for example the end user can group either on country, region, city, or no grouping.
The result is to be used in an ssrs report.

so I would write a query like this:

```
@value = CASE WHEN @dropdown=1 THEN ', foo.country' ELSE ', foo.region'

@sqlquery = 'select name '+@value+' from foo group by field1'+ @value + ';'

EXEC(@sqlquery);
```

This does work as expected in management studio (*if i define variables and assign something to @dropdown*);

I'm a bit at loss on how to implement this in an ssrs report: I want the user to be able to choose no grouping (leave the @value empty)
Visual studio will not be able to 'see' the field and therefore allow to add it in a tablix

Comment: what will be your display if no grouping is selected? all Country, Region, City? What if only country selected? Can you share a sample of your required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
1. Create a parameter GroupBy
[image]

2. Create your data set. Don't directly write your query in to box, use expression instead.
   [image]
3. Write your query like this:
   [image]

I think you probably need to try and adjust your query expression for a while, but it should be the way to go. Good luck.

Comment: This is a much better way to create dynamic queries. I did spend a whole lot of adjusting, missing details like spaces all of the time; but in the end I got it working much easier than other ways. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Avoid users type the grouping (see the @NeilP recommendation), just  create a parameter called `Grouping`, in `Available Values` tab you can specify the dropdown selector values.

[image]

In the Available Values tab use these settings:

[image]

Then in your dataset properties map the SSRS parameter to a T-SQL parameter.

[image]

Now you can use `@Grouping` in your dataset:

```
set @value = CASE WHEN @Grouping = 1 THEN ', foo.country' 
                  WHEN @Grouping = 2 THEN ', foo.region'
                  WHEN @Grouping = 3 THEN ', foo.city'
                  ELSE ''
             END

set @sqlquery = 'select name '+@value+' from foo group by field1'+ @value + ';'
```

The user will be prompt to select one value in the dropdown list:

[image]

You can define a default value used in the report, which lets users run the report without specify any value.

Go to `Default Values` tab in `Parameter Properties` and add `=0` if you want to your report runs without any group by default.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap this in a stored procedure and then call that from the dataset

```
create proc report_1 
@value varchar(200)
as
@sqlquery = 'select name '+@value+' from foo group by field1'+ @value + ';'
EXEC(@sqlquery);
```

Be weary of SQL injection when using dynamic sql, it might be advisable to set a defined list of values for your drop down parameter, either statically or by querying the information schema for column names.

Comment: I have no permissions to create stored procedures. It's not clear to me how ssrs would know the names of the returned fields?